# Error in workspaces in Experience cloud

Tags: digital-experience

I was working in Experience cloud for the site 'Fruit Growers'. There I lost Workspaces automatically under all sites **action** as:[image]

Comment: You have removed the sys admin profile as having access to the digital experience. You need to add it back. You may need to use sfdx to pull the experience bundle, modify the metadata manually then push the change back to the org.

Comment: Is there any other option in Setup  so that I can assign the admin profile to the digital experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the System Administrator profile from the profiles for which the digital experience is accessible you lose the option to access it from Setup.

You essentially have two options to resolve this:

1. Via Setup UI:

   1. If you added permission sets to the access groups for your digital experience then assign one of these to your admin user and logout/login again to see the Workspaces and Builder options.
   2. If you didn't use permission sets but instead used profiles, see if you can create a perm set for the experience - ensure it has access to Setup ("View Setup and Configuration") and can manage experiences ("Manage Experiences") - and assign it to a user with one of your experience profiles. You might then login as that user with this permission and profile to add the System Administrator profile back into the list. Of course, this user must be an internal user and your profiles may only be external ("community") user related, in which case you're probably going to have to use the next option.
2. Use [sfdx](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_intro.htm) to connect to your org (using [force:auth:web:login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_auth.htm#cli_reference_force_auth_web_login)), pull the digital experience (using [force:source:pull](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_pull)), modify the [Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_network.htm) metadata for the experience site to add `admin` to the list of `networkMemberGroups` and finally push this updated metadata back to the org (using [force:source:push](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_push)).

To use the latter, you may need to [enable experience bundles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_migrate_expbundle.htm) on the org first.

Comment: thank you a lot